# Can I have a preg_replace or regex within a MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have two tables that I want to join. The problem is, the data needs some trimming.

```
== Product Description

id              sku                 price

1               674_orange          45.99
2               645_black           59.99
5               592_rubyred         69.99

== Product Attributes

id          sku     description

11          674     lorem ipsum long text description of 674
22          645     lorem ipsum keywords for this item
33          592     lorem ipsum colours on this item
```

I want to join these tables on the SKU. However I need to do a replace since I don't think a `LIKE` or `%` would be accurate enough?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a MySQL equivalent of PHP's preg\_replace?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705437/is-there-a-mysql-equivalent-of-phps-preg-replace)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
select *
from description d
join attributes a on a.sku = substring(sku, 1, locate('_', sku)-1)
```

`locate('_', sku)` gets the position of the `_` in your string

`substring(sku, 1, locate('_', sku)+1)` extracts a substring from `sku`. The substring will start at position `1` and end at the position before `_`. That is why `-1` is used.

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/4258)

Comment: Thanks, can you explain it please? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM ProductDescription pd 
INNER JOIN ProductAttributes pa ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(pd.sku, '_', 1) = pa.sku ;
```