# mySQL replace string + additional string with a static value

Tags: mysql, regex, replace

Unlike PHP, I don't believe mySQL has any `preg_replace()` feature, only matching via REGEXP.  Here are the strings I have in the code:

```
http://ourcompany.com/theapplestore/...
http://ourcompany.com/anotherstore/...
http://ourcompany.com/yetanotherstore/...
```

As you can see, there is a constant in there, `http://ourcompany.com/`, but there is also a variable string namely `theapplestore`, `anotherstore`, etc. etc.

I want to replace the constant string, plus the variable string(s), and then the trailing slash (/) after the variable string(s), with a **single shortcode value**, namely `{{store url=''}}`

**EDIT**
If it helps, the store codes are always the same length, they are going to be
`sch131785`
`sch185399`
`sch634019`
etc.
i.e., they are all 9 characters long

How would I do this?  Thanks.

Comment: Is the URL the full column's content or is there more to it?

Comment: TAYQ, there is more than just that (it's a `TEXT` field).  AND there is more than just one instance of this pattern.

Comment: I can't see an easy way to do it in mysql in that case; there are no wildcards in the `replace` function. I'd pull the whole column into PHP, run the `preg_replace` on it, then send it back in an `update`. There are also addons to mysql that people have used for this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql ("brute force method" at the end is also an interesting idea)

Comment: If I knew how to do it, I'd mark my own question as a possible duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705437/is-there-a-mysql-equivalent-of-phps-preg-replace :)

Comment: The answer is a previous thread; wouldn't that be a duplicate? There are ways to do this but none with a simple native mysql function. You could also try, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001172/mysql-for-replace-with-wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

I thought this might be useful: there is currently NO WAY to do this in mysql.  Find using REGEXP, yes; replace, no.  That said, there is another post with an extension library mentioned, `sagi`:

[Is there a MySQL equivalent of PHP's preg_replace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705437/is-there-a-mysql-equivalent-of-phps-preg-replace)

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB-10.0.5 has REGEXP_REPLACE(), REGEXP_INSTR() and REGEXP_SUBSTR()

Answer (score -1):

You can use following regex,

```
(ourcompany.com\/\w+\/)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mB9oC8/1)

Uses the concept of [Group Capture](http://regexone.com/lesson/11)

Comment: I appreciate your effort however this is more a matter of using MYSQL to replace the string, not recognize it.  I have used various MYSQL expressions for replacing and evaluating strings but not one that does this.